# Is it possible to map a command to only the Alt key in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to bind a command in emacs to the Alt key (not some combination of Alt+ where Alt is behaving as Meta)? What I want to do is to bind tmm-menubar command to the Alt key (rather than F10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terminals, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Meta</kbd> is only a *modifier*, it does not send any sequence when pressed. So you cannot map anything to it.

(I don't know about the graphical versions of emacs.)

Comment: It's also the case for graphical versions of emacs.

Comment: Booo - oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Grawity has the simple (and correct) answer.

However, depending on your OS, there may be other options for you.  You could remap the <kbd>Alt</kbd> to be some other, non-modifier key, perhaps one not available on your keyboard (like <kbd>F15</kbd>).  In general this will be done universally, which means it will affect all applications, something you may not want.  However, it is possible that your OS supports application-specific mappings.  Just throwing out alternatives.

By way of example, I'm running Ubuntu and I've re-mapped the Caps-Lock key be the Windows key, so that it brings up my OS's 'Start' menu, leaving the real Windows key to be the <kbd>Super</kbd> modifier key.  I've done this for all applications, but that's fine for me.